# Issue on Tracing Geometric Network with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geometric-network

I am trying to run this ArcPy example from ESRI [TraceGeometricNetwork example 2](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/trace-geometric-network.htm) as:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Local variables:
Water_Net = "C:/GeometricNetworks/Montgomery.gdb/Water/Water_Net"
Flags = "C:/GeometricNetworks/Montgomery.gdb/Water/Flags"
Water_Net_2 = "Water_Net"

# Process: Trace Geometric Network
arcpy.TraceGeometricNetwork_management(Water_Net, Water_Net_2, Flags, "FIND_PATH", "", "", "Friction_Factor", "Friction_Factor", "", "NO_TRACE_ENDS", "", "", "", "AS_IS", "Friction_Factor", "Friction_Factor", "1-10", "AS_IS")
```

but I am getting this error on running the code

> Message File Name Line Position  Traceback 
>   **call** C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py 196  syncreq
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py 71 
>   sync_request C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py 431  serve
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py
>   379 
>   _recv C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py 337  recv
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py 50
>   read C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py 166 
>   exceptions.EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host

[image]

Can you please let me know what is happening? and How I can fix this?

Comment: It appears you have copied the sample code from the help file _in verbatim_ so unless you just happen to have exactly the same dataset, then it won't work. Do you weight fields called "Friction_Factor" in your dataset for example?

Comment: What happens if you run this code from ArcMap Python window instead of PyScripter?